# Converting GPKG to GDB-Feature Class with gdal.VectorTranslate

Tags: python, gdal, convert, file-geodatabase, geopackage

I am trying to convert a geopackage (GPKG) to a ESRI GDB feature class using `gdal.VectorTranslate()`. My code is like:

```py
translate_options = gdal.VectorTranslateOptions(format="OpenFileGDB", accessMode="overwrite", layerName="My_Regions")

gdal.VectorTranslate(path_to_my_gdb, path_to_my_gpkg, options=translate_options)
```

Unfortunately, nothing happens - I also tried using the driver `FileGDB` but without success. The path to my geodatabase ends with the indication of the geodatabase itself but I also tried appending an output feature class name to the path e.g. "..\test.gdb\My_Regions" but also without success

It works fine when I converted the geopackage to an ESRI Shapefile but I could not do it from any format to a GDB.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Please edit your question to specify what version of GDAL you use and, if [less than 3.6](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/openfilegdb.html), if you've installed a version of GDAL that includes the Esri FileGDB driver and FileGDB API.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me with the following code. GDAL version 3.7.1 with Python 3.9.5.

```py
from osgeo import gdal, ogr

gdal.UseExceptions()
translate_options = gdal.VectorTranslateOptions(format="OpenFileGDB",accessMode="overwrite", layerName="states")
ds = gdal.VectorTranslate("new2.gdb","states2.gpkg",options=translate_options)
ds = None
```

Test with ogrinfo from the command line :

```
ogrinfo new2.gdb
INFO: Open of `new2.gdb'
      using driver `OpenFileGDB' successful.
Layer: states (Multi Polygon)
```

Comment: Oh dear.... I think my gdal-version is too old. Thanks for that quick response!